# "topological operators" on measurable subsets of $S\times \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $(S,\mathcal{S})$ be an arbitrary measurable space and $\mathcal{B}$ be the Borel-$\sigma$-Algebra over the reals $\mathbb{R}$. For $U\in\mathcal{S}\otimes \mathcal{B}$, the product-$\sigma$-Algebra over $S\times\mathbb{R}$,
let ${}_s U = \{ u : (s,u)\in U \} \in \mathcal{B}$ be the "$s$-slice" of U along $s\in S$ (it is Borel-measurable due to Fubini).

For an arbitrary subset $R\subset \mathbb{R}$ denote by

- $R^{\,\text{int}} = \{ r\in \mathbb{R} : \exists \varepsilon>0 : (r-\varepsilon,r+\varepsilon) \subset R \}$ its interior.
- $R^{\,\text{cl}} = \{ r\in \mathbb{R} : \forall \varepsilon>0 : (r-\varepsilon,r+\varepsilon) \cap R \neq \emptyset \}$ its closure.
- $R^{\,\text{iso}} = \{ r\in R : \exists \varepsilon>0 : (r-\varepsilon,r+\varepsilon) \cap R = \{r\} \}$ the set of its isolated points.
- $R^{\,\text{ni}} = R\setminus R^{\,\text{iso}}$ the set of its non-isolated points.
- $R^{\,\text{lim}} = (R^{\,\text{cl}})^{\,\text{ni}}$ the set of its limit points.

For $U$ one can define $U^{\,\text{int}}$ by applying the operator on every $s$-slice of $U$, i.e. $U^{\,\text{int}} = \bigcup_{s\in S} \{s\} \times ({}_s U)^{\,\text{int}}$; and in the same manner
$U^{\,\text{cl}}$, $U^{\,\text{iso}}$, etc.

QUESTION: Which of these sets $U^{\,\text{int}}$, $U^{\,\text{cl}}$, etc. 
inherits the measurability from $U$ (i.e. is an element of $\mathcal{S}\otimes\mathcal{B}$) ?

I tried the standard ways of using some monotone class argument, but I'm stuck.

Thx.

EDIT: mixed up some notations. Question comes from a probability theory context where $(S,\mathcal{S})=(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ is the underlying measurable space. Any "Omegas" should be purged.

Comment: what does $\Omega$ denote?